# Keycloak on Kubernetes high availability cluster (with ldap as user federation) using codecentrics Helm Charts

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, high-availability

We wanted to set up a high available Keycloak cluster on Kubernetes (with ldap as a user federation). We decided to use [codecentrics helm charts](https://github.com/codecentric/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/keycloak) since we were trying them out for a single Keycloak instance setup and that worked well. For the cluster we ran into a few issues while trying to set up everything correctly and didn't find the best sources in the wide internet. Therefore I decided to write a short summary what our main issues where and how we got through them.

Solutions to our problems where described on [this website](https://www.kainos.pl/blog/keycloak-ha-setup-in-multinode-kubernetes-cluster/) (amongst others), but things are described kind of very briefly and felt partly incomplete.

Issues we faced where:

1. Choosing the correct `jgroups.discoveryProtocol`
2. Adding the correct `discoveryProperties`
3. Parts that need to be overridden in your own `values.yaml`

Bonus issues (we already faced with the single instance setup):

1. Setting up an truststore to connect ldap as a user federation via ladps
2. Adding a custom theme for keycloak

I will try and update this if things change due to codecentrics updating their helm charts.

Thanks to codecentrics for providing the helm charts by the way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**
This is the way we set it up - I hope this is helpful, but I do not take responsibility for configuration errors and resulting security flaws. Also we went through many different sources on the internet, I am sorry that I can't give credits to all of them, but it has been a few days since than an I can't get them together anymore...

### CODECENTRIC CHART VERSION < 9.0.0

**The main issues:**
**1. Choosing the correct jgroups.discoveryProtocol:**
I will not explain things here but for us the correct protocol to use was `org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING`. Find out more about the protocols (and general cluster setup) [here](https://www.keycloak.org/2019/05/keycloak-cluster-setup.html).

```
discoveryProtocol: org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING
```

With JDBC_PING jgroups will manage instance discovery. Therefore and for caching user sessions  the database provided for keycloak will be enhanced with extra tables, e.g. `JGROUPSPING`.

**2. Setting up the discoveryProperties:**
This needs to be set to

```
discoveryProperties: >
      "datasource_jndi_name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS"
```

to avoid an error like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Either the 4 configuration properties starting with 'connection_' or 
the datasource_jndi_name must be set
```

**3. Other parts that need to be set** (as mostly described in the readme of codecentrics github and in the comments of the values.yaml in github as well):

- setting the `clusterDomain` according to your cluster
- setting the number of `replicas` greater than 1 to enable clustering
- setting the `service.type`: We went with `ClusterIP` but it also can work with other setups like `LoadBalancer` depending on your setup
- optional but recommended: Setting either `maxUnavailable` or `minAvailable` to always have sufficient pods available according to your needs.
- setting up our Ingress (which looks pretty much standard):

```
 ingress:
    enabled: true
    path: /
    annotations: {
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    }
    hosts:
      - your.host.org
```

**Bonus issues:**

**1. The truststore:**
To have Keycloak communicate with ldap via ldaps we had to set up a truststore with the certificate of our ldap in it:

Receive the certificate from ldap and save it somewhere:

```sh
openssl s_client -connect your.ldap.domain.org < /dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /path/to/ldap.cert
```

Create a new keystore:

```sh
keytool -genkey -alias replserver \
-keyalg RSA -keystore /path/to/keystore.jks \
-dname "CN=AddCommonName, OU=AddOrganizationalUnit, O=AddOrganisation, L=AddLocality, S=AddStateOrProvinceName, C=AddCountryName" \
-storepass use_the_same_password \
-keypass use_the_same_password \
-deststoretype pkcs12
```

Add the downloaded certificate to the keystore:

```sh
keytool -import -alias ldaps -file /path/to/ldap.cert -storetype JKS -keystore path/to/keystore.jks
```

Type in the required password: `use_the_same_password`.
Trust the certificate by typing 'yes'.

Provide the keystore in a configmap:

```sh
kubectl create configmap cert-keystore --from-file=path/to/keystore.jks
```

Enhance your values.yaml for the truststore:

Add and mount the config map:

```
extraVolumes: |
    - name: cert-keystore
      configMap:
        name: cert-keystore

extraVolumeMounts: |
    - name: cert-keystore
      mountPath: "/keystore/"
      readOnly: true
```

Tell java tu use it:

```
javaToolOptions: >-
    -[maybe some other settings of yours]
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/keystore/keystore.jks
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<<keystore_password>>
```

Since we didn't want to upload the keystore password to git we added a step to our pipeline where it gets `sed` into the `values.yaml`, replacing the `<<keystore_password>>`.

**2. Adding a custom theme:**
Mainly we are providing a docker container with our custom theme in it:

```
extraInitContainers: |
    - name: theme-provider
      image: docker_repo_url/themeContainer:version
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command:
        - sh
      args:
        - -c
        - |
          echo "Copying theme..."
          cp -R /custom-theme/* /theme
      volumeMounts:
        - name: theme
          mountPath: /theme
```

Add and mount the theme:

```
extraVolumes: |
    - name: theme
      emptyDir: {}

extraVolumeMounts: |
    - name: theme
      mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/custom-theme
```

You now should be able to choose the custom theme in the Keycloak admin UI via `Realm Settings -> Themes`.

### CODECENTRIC CHART VERSION 9.0.0 to 9.3.2 (and maybe higher)

**1. Clustering**
We are still going with JDBC_PING since we had problems with DNS_PING as described in the Codecentric Repo readme:

```
extraEnv: |
  ## KEYCLOAK CONFIG
  - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
    value: "true"
  ### CLUSTERING
  - name: JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL
    value: org.jgroups.protocols.JDBC_PING
  - name: JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES
    value: 'datasource_jndi_name=java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS'
  - name: CACHE_OWNERS_COUNT
    value: "2"
  - name: CACHE_OWNERS_AUTH_SESSIONS_COUNT
    value: "2"
```

With the service set up as ClusterIP:

```
service:
  annotations: {}
  labels: {}
  type: ClusterIP
  loadBalancerIP: ""
  httpPort: 80
  httpNodePort: null
  httpsPort: 8443
  httpsNodePort: null
  httpManagementPort: 9990
  httpManagementNodePort: null
  extraPorts: []
```

**2. 502 Error Ingress Problem**
We encountered a 502 error with Codecentrics chart 9.x.x for which fixing took a while to figure out. A solution for this is also described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/502-error-ingress-keycloak-response), where we took our inspiration but for us the following ingress setup was enough:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  servicePort: http
  # Ingress annotations
  annotations: {
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx,
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: 128k,
  }
```

### CODECENTRIC CHART VERSION 9.5.0 (and maybe higher)

Updating to 9.5.0 needs to be tested. Especially if desired to go with KUBE_PING and maybe even Autoscaling.
I will update after testing if something changed significantly.

Comment: Would this also work for multiple themes? I have multiple themes in a git repository and I need to install them all on init when deploying the Keycloak.

Comment: I think it should, but I never tried it. Just try it out and let us know...